# Where is Golthag?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-arena

During the main quest of Arena, when asking for location of Fang Lair, the queen of Rihad in Hammerfell tells you:

> Welcome to Rihad, (players name). I am Queen Blubamka, and I agree to tell you about Fang Lair, for a favor. You see, not too long ago a band of goblins, led by **Golthog the Dark** attacked this stronghold. They carried away with them much treasure, including a parchment which held within its writings clues to decipher the part of the Elder Scrolls which spoke of the location of the legendary Fang Lair. **Golthog** and his goblins fled to an ancient and ruined fortress called Stonekeep, outside the city...

Then, after you return the parchment to her from Stonekeep, she gives her thanks and mentions that she "*hope[s] you put Golthog into an early grave as well.*"

I cleared out nearly all of Stonekeep and didn't see any sort of Goblin Chieftain or boss type creature? Did I miss him or did the developers just forget to put him in the game or something? Where is he?

I couldn't find anything about it on the wiki.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The reference is just talk - he doesn't exist in game.

In the notes on [this page](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Arena:Fang_Lair#Stonekeep) of the Wiki it explains that her reference to Golthog is "just talk" and that he cannot be encountered. From the wiki (emphasis mine):

> In her description of what you have to do in Stonekeep, Queen Blubamka
>   makes a passing mention about the goblin leader, Golthog, being in
>   Stonekeep. **This is just talk** and has nothing to do with your quest.
>   You will not have to fight Golthog **nor are you even able to encounter**
>   **him**.

Disclaimer: I haven't played much of Arena, but the UESP is a very reliable source for the games I have played.